# Using a binary semaphore as a Mutex - is it Starvation free?

Tags: synchronization, mutex, semaphore

Consider the following usage:

```
Shared data: semaphore lock; // initially lock = 1
...
down(lock);
CRITICAL SECTION
up(lock);
```

does this code satisfy starvation freedom (i.e. if a process waits to get inside the CS, it will succeed eventually)?

Comment: Looks like you pasted pseudo-code. What kind of 'semaphore' is 'lock'? What are `down` and `up`?

Comment: @ArjunShankar: I would imagine that `down` and `up` are the standard operations that one associates with a semaphore.

Comment: Anyway, assuming that `down(lock)` is a way to obtain exclusive access, it really depends on whether or not `down(lock)` is fair. i.e. if multiple threads are waiting on it, what is the logic that decides which of them wins.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I see what you mean after I read that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Function_name_etymology). Still doesn't change the fact that this really depends on how `down` is implemented.

Comment: Or am I misinformed, and is `down` always associated with a queue?

Comment: @ArjunShankar - Oli is right about Down and Up operations. I guess that you are right as well, it depends on the next-process-to-run policy of the semaphore. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the policy used in choosing a thread when multiple threads are waiting at `down(lock)`.

e.g.

1. If this policy is based around a queue, you are guaranteed to be starvation free.
2. If one of multiple waiting threads is chosen arbitrarily, then you can have starvation by sheer bad luck.
3. If it is based on a priority, then low priority threads will starve as long as high priority ones keep requesting a lock.

For example, Java's counting [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#Semaphore%28int,%20boolean%29), when being created, can be configured to be 'fair' or not. Here, 'fair' refers to the fact that waiting threads will be put in a FIFO so that threads that have waited longest are executed first.